# Continue interrupted download through socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to continue interrupted download from server to client.

Server code for sending:

```
long fileLength = file.length();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        int bytesRead = 0;
        long bytesReadAmount = 0;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[6 * PACKET_SIZE];

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        try {
            BufferedInputStream bufferedIS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedIS.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(byteArray, (int)existingFileSize, bytesRead);
                bytesReadAmount += bytesRead;
                System.out.println("File sending " + fileName + " (send" + bytesReadAmount + " byte, remain " +
                        (fileLength - bytesReadAmount));
            }
            System.out.println("File transfer end");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File transfer error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dataOS.flush();
            socket.close();
        }
```

Client code for receiving

```
long bytesReadAmount = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        long size = 0;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[6 * Server.PACKET_SIZE];

        try {
            File file = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH + fileName);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOS = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOS);

            while ((bytesRead = dataIS.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
                bufferedOS.write(byteArray, (int)existingFileSize, bytesRead);
                bytesReadAmount += bytesRead;
                System.out.println("File receiving " + fileName + " (" + bytesReadAmount + " bytes received)");
            }
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " sending OK");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection interrupted");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Large file sending from beginning to end works good, but download continue after interrut doesn't (sending is not working when I'm trying to continue interrupted file). Also, when I send full file, the copy's size is different from original for some bytes. Please, help to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

The `offset` you are using in `write(byteArray, (int)existingFileSize, bytesRead)` is the offset in the `byteArray` not the original file.  I suggest you use `skip()` to skip data to read or write and **append** to a file when restarting (by setting append in the FileOutputStream constructor)